# How to transfer parameters to the function in onComplete event (Lua + Corona)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How to transfer parameters to the function in onComplete event (Lua + Corona SDK)

```
transition.to(obj, {time = 1000, x = toEnemy.x, y = toEnemy.y, onComplete = onHit} )

----
transition.to( target, params )
----

params is:

params.time
params.transition
params.delay
params.delta
params.onStart
params.onComplete
```

there isn't "params.onCompleteParams", but I want to transfer parameters to my

function without using global variables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lua functions are actually [*closures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). This means that they capture the values of local variables outside the function that are in their scope.

By using an anonymous function as the `onComplete` handler, you can do the following:

```
-- save 'parameters' you need to pass as local variables
local paramToPass = 'hello'
local paramToPass2 = 'world'
transition.to(obj, { time = 1000, x = toEnemy.x, y = toEnemy.y,
    -- use an anonymous function as the onComplete handler
    -- it captures the values of any local variables it references
    onComplete = function(obj)
        -- call your original function with your additional parameters...
        onHit(obj, paramToPass, paramToPass2) 
    end
})
```

Comment: yeah, I know that, but I want to do that without this "saved 'parameters'". But now, after I looked documentation it's seems to me that there isn't more "beauty" variant. Thanks alot!